# User Inputs in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I was just wondering how would I be able to reference two different things in a user's input on a single line. For example:

User input: `test "John" "Jack"`

I would just want to individualized John and Jack from each other. Here's something I have written so far but not sure if it is right.

```
main :: IO ()

readStrings = do
    strings <- readStrings 
    test strings 
...

readStrings :: IO [String]
readStrings = fmap (map read.words) getLine

test :: String -> String -> IO [String]
...
```

They are both passed on to strings in `strings <- readStrings`, and I'm not really sure how to get them separate. The two would them be used in the `test` function

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching.

```
readStrings = do
    strings <- readStrings
    case strings of
        [john, jack] -> test john jack
        _ -> -- what should happen if the user types too many or two few things?
```